# Querying JSON from Minioclient with where clause not working

Tags: sql, json, minio

I have a well formatted JSON file in minio. Im using minio client(mc.exe) to query the storage passing the parameter like below

```
mc sql --query "select * from s3object where AssetName = 'R410ESC01'" play/my-bucket/sample.json

mc sql --recursive --query "select * from s3object where AssetName = 'R410ESC01'" play/my-bucket/sample.json
```

I get the error message:

> Unable to run sql InternalError:"cannot compare values of
>   different types"

Not sure whats wrong with the query. 
The below query works fine, giving me the entire json file.

```
mc sql --query "select * from s3object" play/my-bucket/sample.json
```